# generar un vector con los primeros 100 números primos, luego pedir al usuario cuantos números primos quiere ver

Tags: java, array

Como se lee en el titulo pues ese es el problema como tal, yo nuevo en esto y estoy aprendiendo de manera autodidacta, al buscar información encuentro cosas parecidas pero nada que se acerque a solucionar el problema.

No sé qué estoy haciendo mal o bueno se que estoy haciendo mal pero no se como corregirlo pues me esta dando los numeros pares, no primos.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       int num=0,cprim=0,n;
       Scanner TC = new Scanner (System.in);
       int []tam = new int [100];
       while (cprim==tam.length){
           num+=1;
           if (num%2!=0){
               tam[cprim]=num++; 
               cprim++;
           }
       }
       System.out.println(" ¿Cuantos numeros primos desea ver? ");
       n= TC.nextInt();
       for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
           System.out.println( tam[i]+", ");
       }
       
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Pues `num%2!=0` va a validar si num es divisible por 2 sin residuo (es decir, si es par). Tu criterio para definir si es primo es incorrecto :)

Answer (score 6):

la validación si es un número primo es incorrecta

> if (num%2!=0)

Lo que hace esa validación es verificar si no es un número par.
Personalmente me gusta trabajar con métodos para cada acción a realizar; para tu caso voy a crear 3 métodos: 1 para validar si es un número primo, 1 para mostrar los números primos y el método `main`.

Te dejo el código comentado

```
public class NumerosPrimos {
    static int[]vectorPrimos;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        int contador = 0; //Para validar la cantidad de números primos
        vectorPrimos=new int[100]; //vector para guardar los 100 números primos
        int i=2; //el primer número a evaluar si es primo
        
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        while(contador<100){            
            if(esPrimo(i)){
                vectorPrimos[contador]=i;
                contador++; //incrementamos por cada número primo
            }
            i++; //siguiente número a evaluar si es primo            
        } 
        
        System.out.println("Cuanto primos desea mostrar");
        mostrarPrimos(sc.nextInt()); 
    }
    
    public static boolean esPrimo(int numero){
        int contador = 2;
        boolean primo=true;
        while ((primo) && (contador!=numero)){
          if (numero % contador == 0) //validamos cuando no es primo
            primo = false;
          contador++;
        }
        return primo;
    }
    
    public static void mostrarPrimos(int cantidad){
        for(int i=0;i<cantidad;i++){
            System.out.print(vectorPrimos[i]+", "); //mostramos los primos
        }
    }
}
```

`vectorPrimos` es variable de clase para acceder desde cualquier método de la clase.

**Observación**
Para esta oportunidad he creado la variable de clase y los métodos de forma `static` para no tener que crear un objeto de la clase `NumerosPrimos` sino llamar a los métodos de forma directa.

Answer (score 4):

Puedes mejorar el bastante la rapidez de tu programa si aplicas algoritmos para hallar los números primos, en este caso sugiero el [algoritmo de Atkin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin)

Matemáticamente deben de cumplirse algunas condiciones matemáticas, las cuales se explican en los métodos `applyWheelFactorization` y `discardSquarePerfects`

Con ello generamos un arreglo booleano el cual podemos consultar rápidamente para saber si un número es primo. Sin embargo, este método está limitado al tamaño del arreglo, no a los números primos que realmente quieres. El pro de esto, es que tienes un performance mucho mayor que en otros métodos.

## Código propuesto

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class StackOverflow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SieveOfAtkin sieveOfAtkin = new SieveOfAtkin(600);
        int n = 100;
        try {
            System.out.println(sieveOfAtkin.getNPrimeArray(n));
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println("El tamiz de Atkin actual tiene menos de " + n +" números primos");
        }

    }

    private static class SieveOfAtkin {
        private final int limit;
        private final int sqrt_limit;
        private boolean[] sieve;

        public SieveOfAtkin(int limit) {
            this.limit = limit;
            this.sqrt_limit = (int) Math.sqrt(limit);
            initSieve();
        }

        /**
         * Devuelve el valor booleano de {@code sieve[number]}
         * @param number prime number
         * @return {@code sieve[number]}
         */
        public boolean isPrime(int number) {
            if (number > limit)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("The argument \"number\" must be lesser than \"limit\"");
            if (number < 1)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("There are not negative primes");
            return sieve[number];
        }

        /**
         * Este método retorna una lista con los primeros {@code n_primes} números primos
         * limitado a su existencia dentro de {@code limit}
         * @param n_primes indica cuántos números primos deseas obtener
         * @return una lista con los primeros {@code n_primes} números primos
         * limitado a su existencia dentro de {@code limit}
         * @throws IllegalArgumentException si hay menos de n números primos
         */
        private List<Integer> getNPrimeArray(int n_primes) throws IllegalArgumentException{
            return IntStream.range(2, Integer.MAX_VALUE)
                    .filter(this::isPrime)
                    .limit(n_primes)
                    .boxed()
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }

        public void initSieve() {
            this.sieve = new boolean[limit];
            Arrays.fill(sieve, false);
            // SieveOfAtkin funciona únicamente con números mayores a 3
            for (int i = 2; i < 4 && i < limit; i++)
                sieve[i] = true;

            applyWheelFactorization();
            discardSquarePerfects();
        }

        /**
         * Cambia sieve[n] a verdadero si alguna de las siguientes
         * condiciones se cumple para un par de números enteros
         * cualesquiera { (x, y) | x <= sqrt_limit ∩ y <= sqrt_limit }:
         *     a) Con n = (4 * x * x) + (y * y) tenga un número impar de
         *          soluciones a la ecuación n % 12 = 1 o n % 12 = 5.
         *     b) Con n = (3 * x * x) + (y * y) tenga un número impar de
         *          soluciones a la ecuación n % 12 = 7
         *     c) Con n = (3 * x * x) - (y * y) | x > y tenga un número impar de
         *            soluciones a la ecuación and n % 12 = 11
         */
        public void applyWheelFactorization() {
            for (int x = 1; x <= sqrt_limit; x++) {
                for (int y = 1; y <= sqrt_limit; y++) {
                    // first quadratic using m = 12 and r in R1 = {r : 1, 5}
                    int n = (4 * x * x) + (y * y);
                    if (n < limit && (n % 12 == 1 || n % 12 == 5)) {
                        sieve[n] = !sieve[n];
                    }
                    // second quadratic using m = 12 and r in R2 = {r : 7}
                    n = (3 * x * x) + (y * y);
                    if (n < limit && (n % 12 == 7)) {
                        sieve[n] = !sieve[n];
                    }
                    // third quadratic using m = 12 and r in R3 = {r : 11}
                    n = (3 * x * x) - (y * y);
                    if (x > y && n < limit && (n % 12 == 11)) {
                        sieve[n] = !sieve[n];
                    } // end if
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Descarta todos los cuadrados perfectos como números primos, pues
         * {@link #applyWheelFactorization() applyWheelFactorization}
         * sólo elimina algunos de ellos
         */
        public void discardSquarePerfects() {
            for (int r = 5; r * r < limit; r++) {
                if (sieve[r]) {
                    for (int i = r * r; i < limit; i += r * r)
                        sieve[i] = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

## Comparación de eficiencia

Comparación de performance con el algoritmo propuesto por [HowToDoInJava](https://howtodoinjava.com/java-examples/find-first-n-prime-numbers/)

Resultados de ejecución de los métodos `getNPrimeArray` en tiempo (nano segundos):

| Intento | HTDIJ | Atkins | Gana |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15738900 | 06870199 | Atkins |
| 2 | 13388100 | 05334699 | Atkins |
| 3 | 10170100 | 05314299 | Atkins |

Como ven la ejecución tarda menos de la mitad en completarse. Los test se corrieron por separado para evitar desventajas de ejecución y para ello se usó el siguiente código de **HowToDoInJava**:

```java
private static class HowToDoInJavaAlgorithm {
    private List<Integer> getNPrimeArray(int n_primes) {
        return IntStream.range(2, Integer.MAX_VALUE)
                .filter(this::isPrime)
                .limit(n_primes)
                .boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private boolean isPrime(int number) {
        if(number <= 2)
            return number == 2;
        else
            return  (number % 2) != 0
                    &&
                    IntStream.rangeClosed(3, (int) Math.sqrt(number))
                            .filter(n -> n % 2 != 0)
                            .noneMatch(n -> (number % n == 0));
    }
}
```

Lo más importante a ver es que `getNPrimeArray` es un método bastante tardado, pues genera una Lista, por lo cual no es tan útil para la comparación de eficiencia, por lo tanto, ahora compararemos los métodos `isPrime` para ver la verdadera diferencia, además de su otra ventaja, pues una vez generado el arreglo o el ***sieve***, se puede usar mucho más rápido para obtener los n números primos.

Si ejecutamos el siguiente código podremos ver la notoria diferencia.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class StackOverflow{

    static final int max = 15_000;
    static final int min = 100;
    static final int n_test = 100_000;

    public static void main (String... args) {
        Random random = new Random();
        int[] numbers2check = random.ints(n_test, min, max + 1).toArray();

        Thread htdij = new Thread(() -> testHtdinjEfficiency(numbers2check));
        Thread atkins = new Thread(() -> testAtkinsEfficiency(numbers2check));

        htdij.start();
        atkins.start();
    }

    public static void testHtdinjEfficiency(int[] random) {
        long[] timing = new long[random.length];
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        HowToDoInJavaAlgorithm howToDoInJavaAlgorithm = new HowToDoInJavaAlgorithm();
        howToDoInJavaAlgorithm.isPrime(random[0]);
        timing[0] = System.nanoTime() - start;

        for (int i = 1; i < random.length; i++) {
            start = System.nanoTime();
            howToDoInJavaAlgorithm.isPrime(random[i]);
            timing[i] = System.nanoTime() - start;
        }

        Arrays.sort(timing);

        double average = Arrays.stream(timing).average().orElse(Double.NaN);
        long frequency_50 = Arrays.stream(timing).filter(e -> e <= 50).count();

        System.out.println("htdij\n======\nMin: " + timing[0] + "\tMax: " + timing[random.length -1] +
                "\tAverage: " + average + "\nFrequency(n <= 50): " + frequency_50);
    }

    public static void testAtkinsEfficiency(int[] random) {
        long[] timing = new long[random.length];

        long start = System.nanoTime();
        SieveOfAtkin sieveOfAtkin = new SieveOfAtkin(max + 1);
        sieveOfAtkin.isPrime(random[0]);
        timing[0] = System.nanoTime() - start;

        for (int i = 1; i < random.length; i++) {
            start = System.nanoTime();
            sieveOfAtkin.isPrime(random[i]);
            timing[i] = System.nanoTime() - start;
        }

        Arrays.sort(timing);

        double average = Arrays.stream(timing).average().orElse(Double.NaN);
        long frequency_50 = Arrays.stream(timing).filter(e -> e <= 50).count();

        System.out.println("Atkins\n======\nMin: " + timing[0] + "\tMax: " + timing[random.length -1] +
                "\tAverage: " + average + "\nFrequency(n <= 50): " + frequency_50);

    }
}
```

**Mínimo**

| Intento | HTDIJ | Atkins | Gana |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | Empate |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | Empate |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | Empate |

**Máximo**

| Intento | HTDIJ | Atkins | Gana |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 6536600 | 3305800 | Atkins |
| 2 | 18481000 | 3475000 | Atkins |
| 3 | 25963700 | 4422100 | Atkins |

**Promedio (redondeado)**

| Intento | HTDIJ | Atkins | Gana |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 776 | 168 | Atkins |
| 2 | 1399 | 167 | Atkins |
| 3 | 1236 | 143 | Atkins |

**Frecuencia (timing < 50 ns)**

| Intento | HTDIJ | Atkins | Gana |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11110 | 20813 | Atkins |
| 2 | 15974 | 28628 | Atkins |
| 3 | 17932 | 30261 | Atkins |

Answer (score 2):

A ver si te sirve, lo que hace el código es generar los números primos hasta el número que se le pida

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //instanciamos la clase scanner
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    //pedimos el número hasta el que deseamos conocer los primero
    System.out.print("Hasta que número desea saber los números primos: ");
    //recogemos el número en la variable entera
    int max = teclado.nextInt();

    //imrpimimos el texto
    System.out.println("Son números primos: ");
    //creamos un bucle for con el límite del número introducido
    for(int i = 0; i <= max; i++){
        //recogemos en una variable booleana el return del método esPrimo y enviamos el número
        //correpondiente a la iteración del bucle
        boolean primo = esPrimo(i);
        //si el return es primo, lo sacamos por pantalla
        if (primo){
            System.out.print(i + ", ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
//método que nos dice si el número es primo que recibe por parámetro un entero (el de la iteración del bucle)
public static boolean esPrimo(int numero) {
    // El 0, 1 y 4 no son primos
    if (numero == 0 || numero == 1 || numero == 4) {
        //por lo que en esos números retonramos false
        return false;
    }
    //creamos un bucle para evaluar los números recibidos
    for (int x = 2; x < numero / 2; x++) {
        // Si es divisible por cualquiera de estos números, no es primo
        if (numero % x == 0)
            //si no es primo retornamos falso
            return false;
    }
    // Si no se pudo dividir por ninguno de los de arriba, sí es primo
    return true;
}
```