# ¿Cómo se puede calcular si un numero es primo sin usar "%"?

Tags: algoritmos

Hace poco se me planteó el problema de calcular si un numero es primo, pero con la condición de que no se podía usar el *Mod*, o también conocido como *Modulo* (%). He buscado información en varias páginas web pero sinceramente no encuentro nada que se parezca al problema planteado. He intentado idear el programa, pero aún después de unas horas de pensar y pensar, no consigo llegar con la solución; Agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Comment: Tal vez te ayude [mi respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/479067/generar-un-vector-con-los-primeros-100-n%c3%bameros-primos-luego-pedir-al-usuario-cu/479208#479208), existen algoritmos desde la antigüedad para poder calcular los números primos, en este caso yo utilicé el algoritmo de Atkins (2003)

Comment: De igual manera, te recomiendo leer [este artículo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), para que puedas elaborar mejor tu pregunta, de lo contrario muy probablemente recibas votos negativos y hasta cierren tu pregunta. Como recomendación te diría que añadas lo que has pensado hasta este momento y las etiquetas las cambies por algoritmo. Cuando se usan varias etiquetas, siempre terminan cerradas

Comment: Es muy sencillo aplicar tu propia implementación de la operación de resto de división entera, incluso, siendo los valores primos tales que son enteros positivos, es aún más sencillo implementar esta función. ¿Qué has intentado / averiguado? Tal como está tu pregunta parece que buscas que alguien te haga la tarea.

Comment: @MauricioContreras Tienes razón, admito que eso parece. No obstante, esta pregunta en un principio no era para aplicarla en un lenguaje, de hecho es para un diagrama de flujo donde se dijo que no se podía usar el %. De hecho, ya habia pensado en que se podia comparar el resultado de una division simplemente redondeando un valor, tal como el el Ejemplo de Juan de más abajo. Pero ¿Cómo iba a redondear un numero en un diagrama de flujo en el que solo se pueden usar lo básico de la programación?.  Me disculpo si le he causado incomodidad, solo no había podido llegar a la solución.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes habría que hacerlo viendo si el cociente tiene decimales. Si divides A/B te dará un cociente, si ese cociente es igual al resultado de redondearlo entonces el resto es 0.
Por ejemplo 9/2 da de cociente 4.5, al redondearlo obtienes 4, por tanto los números no son divisibles.
Algo así.

```
        float P=9;
        float D=3;
        double cociente;
        cociente = P/D;
        //double entero = Math.floor(cociente);
        double entero = (int)cociente;
        if(cociente == entero)
            System.out.println("El número es divisible");
        else
            System.out.println("El número NO es divisible");
```

Esto te serviría para saber si dos números son divisibles sin usar %, podrías usar una función con este código para determinar si un número tiene divisores o sea si es primo o no.
**EDITO**
Sin usar Math se puede hacer una conversión de tipos.
Pero sin usar divisiones se puede saber si un número es divisible por otra por sumas. Para saber si 9 es divisible entre 3, se le resta 3 a 9 hasta que de 0 o menos de 0. Si da 0 son divisibles si es negativo no es divisible.
9 - 3 = 6
6 - 3 = 3
3 - 3 = 0
Son divisilbes.
9/4:
9 - 4 = 5
5 - 4 = 1
1 - 4 = -3
Da negativo, no son divisibles.

```
        float P=9;
        float D=3;
        float ac = P;
        while (ac >0)
        {
           ac = ac - D;
        }
        if (ac ==0)
            System.out.println(P+" es divisible entre "+D);
        else    
             System.out.println(P+" NO es divisible entre "+D);
```

Es menos eficiente, pero cumple con lo que pides. Si te das cuenta la división no son más que restas consecutivas. Es en lo que se bse este algoritmo.
**EDITO**
Por el comentario de código no optimizado añado esta solución, una mejora de la primera:

```
       int num = 9;
       int div = 2;
       int resto= num/div*div;
       System.out.print("¿Es divisible "+num+" entre "+ div +"? : "+ (resto== num));
```

Por supuesto esto lo metería en una función devolverá verdadero o falso

Comment: ¿Existe alguna otra forma que no requiera usar una función nativa de las librerías del lenguaje?, como en el ejemplo de @Juan se usa *Math.floor*. Me gustaría saber si se puede resolver solo con las operaciones básicas de un lenguaje (condicionales, bucles y variables).

Comment: Edito la respuesta con dos posibles soluciones.

Comment: ¿Porqué declarar las variables como float? Eso es, aparte de un desperdicio de memoria, una incongruencia con el problema planteado. Hablamos de números primos, por lo cual solo basta enteros, de hecho son enteros positivos todos. La división entre enteros produce enteros, en casi cualquier lenguaje, incluso hay lenguajes que incorporan un operador exclusivo para división entera. Una vez que tienes el resultado de una división entera, para saber si es exacta se calcula el resto (restar el dividendo del resultado multiplicado por el divisor), si es igual a cero entonces es exacta. Saludos

Comment: Es una solución básica, a desarrollar, he puesto el código lo más simple posible para mostrar el algoritmo de resolución.  He interpretado que la solución debe ser lo más simple posible. Por supuesto que es mejorable